# How to set dynamic sender email in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am using simple mail function of Laravel to send mail via SMTP. Mail is getting triggered but the sender email is always appearing to be the username that I set in .env file. I want the sender email to be dynamic.

### .env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=senderemailaddress@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

### controller

```
$data = [
            'message' => $request->message
        ];
        $user['to']=$request->receivermail;
        $user['subject']=$request->subject;
        $user['from']=$request->sendermail;
        $user['sendername']=$request->sendername;
        Mail::send('blog.demoMail',['data'=>$data],function($msg) use ($user,$files,$request){
            $msg->from($user['from'], $user['sendername']);
            $msg->to($user['to']);
            $msg->subject($user['subject']);
            if ($request->hasFile('attachment')){
                $msg->attach($files[0]);
            }
            
                       

            
        });
```

Comment: Be careful with that. Some hosts may not allow emails coming from an off-domain email. You might want to set it as the ReplyTo instead.

Comment: Okay, so my code is right correct? The problem lies on the host right?

Comment: Yes, from what I can tell, your code is correct.

Comment: Is there any other mail driver that I can use for dynamic "sender" email?

Comment: I don't know of any, sorry.